# Translation of "Beowulf"

Tags: english, history, old-english

In the brief span of time I have studied this ancient poem, particularly verses 1829-30, I have read several translations. While observing each individual rendering of the text, it was evident to me that confusion still persists between the translations. Which translation therefore might be considered the most accurate by the top linguists in the world and what was the criteria they used to come to that conclusion?

Comment: Which one do **you** think did it better?

Comment: This isn't a question for linguists -- how could it possibly be settled objectively?

Comment: We might feel like answering your question if you would quote the verses and a few sample translations.

Comment: @fdb- I am crunched for time right now but will enter in the verse you requested: "ic the thusenda thegna bringe, haeletha to helpe." One translation I ca,

Comment: @fdb- came across goes as such: "I will bring to your side a thousand thanes, warriors to help you." Source: Beowulf- Translated... by Howell D. Chickering Jr., Professor of English at Amherst College, 1977, pages 154-155. As with others I have read, each translation seems to be embellished rather than verbatim in content. Can you elaborate on this for me?

Comment: @fdb- I have three other translations now for you and your colleagues to consider. As follows: "thousand then of thanes I shall bring, heroes to help thee." The Oldest English Epic by Francis B. Gummere, 1925 New York, page 102; "With thanes by the thousand I will hasten to help." Beowulf-The Oldest English Epic by Charles W. Kennedy, page 59, 1940 Oxford English Press; & "I will bring thousands of thanes, all heroes, to help you." Beowulf by Kevin Crossley-Holland, 1968, page 82. I await your next response.

Comment: @fdb-Two more translations given hereafter: "I shall come with a thousand thanes, warriors of ours, to render you aid." Beowulf- A Verse Translation and Introduction by Martin Puhvel, page 64, 2006;  "I of that thousand thane, a Bring, a warrior, to a help." Them Also I Must Bring- Addendum, 2011, page 25, by DTB. I am still waiting for some answers to my question. You are invited to do so.

Comment: @fdb- FYI- "hwilum dydon ic the thusenda thegna bringe haeletha to helpe."= "...at times to cause I of that thousand thane, a Bring, a warrior, to a help."     "There are, it may be, so many kinds of voices in the world, and none of them is without signification." 1 Corinthians 14:10. Those who research languages and write dictionaries provide much of that signification. My translation is based principally from a leading Anglo-Saxon dictionary which signifies learned truths from established records. Therefore I must regard it as correct to the best of my ability. Yea or Nay?